# Asp.Core API trying to upload file and store in database: ERROR: 415: Unsupported Media Type

Tags: c#, sql, json, asp.net-core, postman

When trying to create an API that can upload files (and other data) to the database, i am always getting stuck. The API has a raw JSON response with data filling different tables for the database. However, with postman i have to upload the file as form-data or binary file (as the same time as i want to send the raw JSON data), but this never seems to work no matter what i try. So here's the method for uploading files in asp.core (i'm using a viewmodel class for my methods):

```
 if (item.fileuploadresults != null) {

   try {

     foreach(FileUploadResult f in item.fileuploadresults) {
       var parameters = new DynamicParameters();
       parameters.Add("file", f.files);
       parameters.Add("@filename", f.filename);
       parameters.Add("@blob", f.FileBlob);

       var filemessage = await _sqlconnection.QueryAsync < int > ($ @ "INSERT INTO 
       [dbo].[OptionalFile] (file, [FileName], [FileBloB])
         VALUES({
           f.files
         }, @filename, @blob); SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY();
         ", parameters);

         int FileMessageID = filemessage.First();

         //update cross table
         await _sqlconnection.QueryAsync < int > ($ @ "INSERT INTO
        [dbo].[ClaimCrossOptionalFile]
           (ClaimID, FileID) VALUES({
             claimID
           }, {
             FileMessageID
           });
           ");

         }

       }

       catch (Exception ex) {
         int k = 0;
       }

     }
```

The models look like following:

```
public class Service
{    
    public IList<FileUploadResult> fileuploadresults { get; set; }
        
}

public class FileUploadResult
{
    public IFormFile files { get; set; } 

    [MaxLength]
    public byte[] FileBlob { get; set; }

    public long Length { get; set; }

    public string filename { get; set; }
}
```

The raw JSON:

```
{
   "service":"Scheduled service",
   "RequestTypeId":"2",
   "CurrentKilometerreading":"10043",
   "OptionalMessage":"Message3",
   "fileuploadresults":[
      {
         "files":""
      }
   ],
   "works":[
      {
         "title":"Service1",
         "price":"200",
         "id":"1998"
      },
      {
         "title":"Service2",
         "price":"300",
         "id":"1999"
      },
      {
         "title":"labour 1",
         "chargePerHour":"10",
         "hours":"2",
         "price":"20.00",
         "id":"2000"
      },
      {
         "title":"labour2",
         "chargePerHour":"20",
         "hours":"2",
         "price":"40.00",
         "id":"2001"
      },
      {
         "title":"Part 1",
         "pricePerUnit":"10",
         "quantity":"11",
         "price":"110.00",
         "id":"2002"
      },
      {
         "title":"Part 1",
         "pricePerUnit":"10",
         "quantity":"11",
         "price":"110.00",
         "id":"2003"
      }
   ]
}
```

Is it impossible to send both raw json data and form-data in the same request? I've tried changing the content-type in postman as well, with no success.

Thankful for anyone who has any idea on how to proceed.

Comment: "Is it impossible to send both raw json data and form-data in the same request?" pretty much, yes; the body is *either* a form *xor* a raw post body; I guess there's always multi-part MIME, but that's a whole other set of complexity

Comment: What is the exact line you get the exception. also please post your entire API method

Comment: For your case, I think you can use [Custom Model Binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/advanced/custom-model-binding?view=aspnetcore-5.0).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone comes across this problem as well, I have found a solution, you can look at this post: [using jsonData as a key value to send mixed data in asp: Does not update the database with the values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68498411/using-jsondata-as-a-key-value-to-send-mixed-data-in-asp-does-not-update-the-dat).

Answer (score 0):

try using `jsonConvert` and use `[FromForm] string jsonData` in the method