# using jsonData as a key value to send mixed data in asp: Does not update the database with the values

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core, postman, dapper

After trying to mix a fileupload and json data in postman i finally found a method where it is possible to send them both in the same request. Therefore, I have moved my json data to a Key in Postman, so that it becomes possible to send files as well using form-data (Picture below).

[image]

Within the value I have JSON data as following:

```
{
   "WorkshopEmail":"workshopemail",
   "WorkshopContactperson":"workshopcontactperson",
   "WorkshopCellphone":"workshopcellphone",
   "Service":[
      {
         "service":"Claim Airbag",
         "RequestTypeId":"1",
         "DamageDate":"2021-05-03",
         "DamageKilometerreading":"213",
         "LatestServiceDate":"2021-05-03",
         "LatestServiceKilometer":"1223",
         "WorkshopDiagnos":"diagnos workshop",
         "CarOwnerDescription":"carownerdescription",
         "CategoryId":"25",
         "works":[
            {
               "title":"arbete 1 airbag",
               "chargePerHour":"11",
               "hours":"12",
               "price":"132.00",
               "id":"13926"
            },
            {
               "title":"arbete2 airbag",
               "chargePerHour":"1",
               "hours":"2",
               "price":"2.00",
               "id":"13927"
            },
            {
               "title":"part1 airbag",
               "pricePerUnit":"100",
               "quantity":"1",
               "price":"100.00",
               "id":"13928"
            },
            {
               "title":"part2 airbag",
               "pricePerUnit":"100",
               "quantity":"2",
               "price":"200.00",
               "id":"13929"
            }
         ]
      },
      {},
      {},
      {},
      {},
      {}
   ]
}
```

The empty {} just contains more service types. Now when I send the request in Postman i get a 200 OK and when i debug i can see the following (sorry if the picture is blurry):

[image]

¨
*However, my database does not get updated with these values*. Here's the class for inserting data into the tables:

```
public async Task<bool> AddRequest(Request model, List<IFormFile> file, [FromForm] string jsonData)
{
    bool CreateRequest = true;
    int requestID = 0;
    int claimID = 0;
    //bool country = true;

    //First Create the Request
    foreach (Service item in model.Service) 
    {
        //First Create the Request
        if (CreateRequest)
        {

            var parameters = new DynamicParameters();
            parameters.Add("WorkshopEmail", model.WorkshopEmail);
            parameters.Add("WorkshopContactperson", model.WorkshopContactperson);
            parameters.Add("WorkshopCellphone", model.WorkshopCellphone);
            parameters.Add("DamageDate", model.DamageDate);
            parameters.Add("LatestServiceDate", model.LatestServiceDate);
            parameters.Add("LatestServiceKilometer", model.LatestServiceKilometer);
            parameters.Add("DamageKilometerreading", model.DamageKilometerreading);
            parameters.Add("CurrentKilometerreading", model.CurrentKilometerreading);
            parameters.Add("CarOwnerDescription", model.CarOwnerDescription);
            parameters.Add("WorkshopDiagnos", model.WorkshopDiagnos);
            parameters.Add("AmountIncVat", model.AmountIncVat);



            try
            { 
            var requestIDenum = await _sqlconnection.QueryAsync<int>($@"INSERT INTO [dbo].[Request]
                                                    (WorkshopEmail,WorkshopContactperson,WorkshopCellphone,DamageDate,LatestServiceDate,
                                                     LatestServiceKilometer,DamageKilometerreading,CurrentKilometerreading,
                                                     CarOwnerDescription,WorkshopDiagnos,AmountIncVat)
                                                    VALUES
                                                    (@WorkshopEmail,@WorkshopContactperson,@WorkshopCellphone,@DamageDate,@LatestServiceDate,
                                                     @LatestServiceKilometer,@DamageKilometerreading,@CurrentKilometerreading,
                                                     @CarOwnerDescription,@WorkshopDiagnos,@AmountIncVat);SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY();",parameters);
            requestID = requestIDenum.First();
            CreateRequest = false;

            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {

                int hej = 0;
            }
        }
        
        if (item.fileuploadresults != null)
        {
            foreach (FileUploadResult f in item.fileuploadresults)
            {
                var parameters = new DynamicParameters();

                parameters.Add("file", f.filename);

                var filemessage = await _sqlconnection.QueryAsync<int>($@"INSERT INTO [dbo].[OptionalFile] ([FileName])
                                                  VALUES (@file); SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY();", parameters);



                int FileMessageID = filemessage.First(); 

                
                await _sqlconnection.QueryAsync<int>($@"INSERT INTO[dbo].[ClaimCrossOptionalFile]
                                                    (ClaimID,FileID)
                                                    VALUES
                                                    ({claimID},{FileMessageID});");
            }
        }
              

    return true;
    //return list;
}
```

Controller:

```
 [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> AddRequest(List<IFormFile> file, [FromForm] string jsonData)
        {
            // if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            // {

            Request request = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Request>(jsonData); 

            try
            {
                //await _request.AddRequest(request);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                return BadRequest(ex.Message);
            }

            return Ok(); 
        }
```

Interface:

```
Task<bool> AddRequest(Request model, List<IFormFile> file, [FromForm] string jsonData);
```

Sidenote: This is part of the code, as i've tried to keep it short, so perhaps some } or something is missing here, but there's no problem. If i should add the whole code i could perhaps send it in a link or something similar, as it would be a lot to upload here.

However, I do not now how to proceed with this issue at the moment. I've not worked with form-data much before, at least not with passing json as a value. Perhaps there's something I'm missing/have to do in the controller with the json data? I've tried looking for solutions but I've gotten stuck here. The only issue is that the database does not get updated.

Update, the model:

```
 public class Work
    {
        //base for claim
        public string title { get; set; } = "";
        public string chargePerHour { get; set; } = "";
        public string hours { get; set; } = "";
        public string price { get; set; } = "";
        public string id { get; set; } = "";
        public string pricePerUnit { get; set; } = "";
        public string quantity { get; set; } = "";

        //service
        public int rentreasonId { get; set; } = -1;
        public int rentservicecartypeId { get; set; } = -1;

        //tyres
        public int tireserviceId { get; set; } = -1;

        public IList<TireType> tireTypes { get; set; }
        public IList<Labour> labours { get; set; }
        
        public DateTime DateFrom{ get; set; } = DateTime.Parse("1753-01-01");
        public DateTime DateTo { get; set; } = DateTime.Parse("1753-01-01");

        //Insurance
        public string totalAmount { get; set; }
        public string requestInsuranceVatID { get; set; }
        public string vat { get; set; } = "0.0";
        public string totalExclVat { get; set; }="0.0";
        public string totalIncVat { get; set; }="0.0";


    }

    public class Labour
    {
        public string title { get; set; } = "";
        public string chargePerHour { get; set; } = "";
        public string hours { get; set; } = "";

        public string price { get; set; } = "";
    }

    public class TireType
    {
        public string quantity { get; set; } = "";
        public string brand { get; set; } = "";
        public string model { get; set; } = "";

        public string pricePerUnit { get; set; } = "";
        public string price { get; set; } = "";

        public string tireTypeId { get; set; } = "";

        public string widthID { get; set; } = ""; 

        public string heightID { get; set; } = "";

        public string diameterID { get; set; } = "";
    }

    public class Request
    {
        public string WorkshopEmail { get; set; } = "";

        public string WorkshopContactperson { get; set; } = "";

        public string WorkshopCellphone { get; set; } = "";

        public int AmountIncVat { get; set; } = 0;

        #region Claim
        public DateTime DamageDate { get; set; } = DateTime.Parse("1753-01-01");

        public DateTime LatestServiceDate { get; set; } = DateTime.Parse("1753-01-01");

        public int LatestServiceKilometer { get; set; } = 0;

        public int DamageKilometerreading { get; set; } = 0;

        public int CurrentKilometerreading { get; set; } = 0;

        public string CarOwnerDescription { get; set; } = "";

        public string WorkshopDiagnos { get; set; } = "";

        //public string OptionalMessage { get; set; } = "";

        #endregion
        public IList<Service> Service { get; set; }

       
    }

    public class TireTread
    {
        public string tireserviceId { get; set; } = "";
        public string leftfront { get; set; } = "";
        public string rightfront { get; set; } = "";
        public string leftrear { get; set; } = "";
        public string rightrear { get; set; } = "";
        public string added1 { get; set; } = "";
        public string added2 { get; set; } = "";
        public string added3 { get; set; } = "";
        public string added4 { get; set; } = "";
        public string added5 { get; set; } = "";
    }

    public class TireMessage
    {
        public int tireserviceId { get; set; }
        public string message { get; set; }
    }

    public class Service
    {
     //   [JsonProperty("ServiceId")]
        public string RequestTypeId { get; set; } = "";
        public string CategoryId { get; set; } = "-1";
     
  

        public string OptionalMessage { get; set; } = "";

        public IList<Work> works { get; set; }
        public IList<TireTread> treads { get; set; }

        public IList<TireMessage> TireMessages { get; set; }

        //filuppladdning
        public IList<FileUploadResult> fileuploadresults { get; set; }
    }

    //filuppladdning
    public class FileUploadResult
    {
        //public IFormFile files { get; set; } 

        public string filename { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Maybe provide the code for your RequestModel (I would advise to think about a different name, that is pretty generic). Also what value has the Service property when you debug?

Comment: @Sascha i updated.  When i debug i can see the entire json request passed as a value

Comment: When you debug,do `Request model` and `parameters` have value?

Comment: Why do you not use the RequestModel as type in your ASP.NET Core method?

Comment: @YiyiYou no, i can only see the json string..

Comment: @Sascha when  i add Request Model in the AddRequest method in the controller, i get a 415: unsupported media type when i run it in postman...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, in case anyone else comes across this problem. I needed to modify the controller and add this code:

```
 [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> AddRequest(List<IFormFile> file, [FromForm] string jsonData)
        {
            Request request = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Request>(jsonData);

            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }
            try
            {
                await _request.AddRequest(request, file, jsonData);

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                return BadRequest(ex.Message);
            }

            return Ok();
        }
```

Basically adding `request` (that I deserialize in the begining of the method), and adding the `file`, and `jsonData` in an await request, solved the problem. As for the fileuploading, I needed to modify that method as well, to get the filename into the database:

```
if (file != null)
                {

                    foreach (IFormFile f in file)
                    {
                        string filename = Path.GetFileName(f.FileName);
                        var parameters = new DynamicParameters();
                        parameters.Add("file", filename);

                        var filemessage = await _sqlconnection.QueryAsync<int>($@"INSERT INTO 
                        [dbo].[OptionalFile] ([FileName])
                        VALUES (@file); SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY();", parameters);
    
                    }
                
                }
```

Changing these to made it possible to send a request containg both the json key value, and multiple files, in the same request.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly,the json format does not match the model structure.You need to pass json like this(Pay attention to `DamageKilometerreading` and `LatestServiceKilometer`,the type of them are int,so don't use `""`):

```
{
   "WorkshopEmail":"workshopemail",
   "WorkshopContactperson":"workshopcontactperson",
   "WorkshopCellphone":"workshopcellphone",
   "DamageDate":"2021-05-03",
   "DamageKilometerreading":213,
   "LatestServiceDate":"2021-05-03",
   "LatestServiceKilometer":1223,
   "WorkshopDiagnos":"diagnos workshop",
   "CarOwnerDescription":"carownerdescription",
   "Service":[
      {
         "service":"Claim Airbag",
         "RequestTypeId":"1",
         "CategoryId":"25",
         "works":[
            {
               "title":"arbete 1 airbag",
               "chargePerHour":"11",
               "hours":"12",
               "price":"132.00",
               "id":"13926"
            },
            {
               "title":"arbete2 airbag",
               "chargePerHour":"1",
               "hours":"2",
               "price":"2.00",
               "id":"13927"
            },
            {
               "title":"part1 airbag",
               "pricePerUnit":"100",
               "quantity":"1",
               "price":"100.00",
               "id":"13928"
            },
            {
               "title":"part2 airbag",
               "pricePerUnit":"100",
               "quantity":"2",
               "price":"200.00",
               "id":"13929"
            }
         ]
      },
      {},
      {},
      {},
      {},
      {}
   ]
}
```

Then try to add `public string service { get; set; }=""` inService model.